# Integer.parseInt does not parse String to int

Tags: java, type-conversion

The code below is from a Servlet trying to read data from a submitted html form. The variable `fieldValue` is a String and prints correct value (like so `BizStr: 5`) but when I try to parse this value to integer, it does not print anything.

```
for(FileItem uploadItem : uploadItems){
  if(uploadItem.isFormField()){
    String fieldName = uploadItem.getFieldName();
    String fieldValue = uploadItem.getString();
    if(fieldName.equals("business_id")){
        out.println("BizStr: "+ fieldValue +"\n");
        out.println("BizInt: "+ Integer.parseInt(fieldValue )+"\n");
    }
  }
}
```

Why is this string not being parsed into integer?

Comment: Do you have a stack trace from an error?

Comment: I'd suspect there's an extra space there or something, `Integer.parseInt` throws a `NumberFormatException`, which gets eaten somewhere

Comment: Can you please do `out.println("BizInt: "+ Arrays.toString(fieldValue.toCharArray())+"\n");` and edit what that does into your answer

Comment: It does not throw any exception.

Comment: Try surrounding the line with `Integer.parseInt()` with a `try-catch` for `NumberFormatException`, and print the stack trace.

Comment: It either parses the string to a number, or throws an exception... there is no other way.

Comment: @iluxa made a good guess, it may be white space. The following code should strip whitespace (including non-visible characters) from your string if you want to try it. `fieldValue.replaceAll("\\s","")` (Note, that won't change the value of the variable, it will just return it. So you can use that code inside your `parseInt` call or do `fieldValue = fieldValue.replaceAll("\\s","");`)

Comment: @Kyle kinda embarrassed, yes you are right, it is due to whitespace. thank you all

Comment: Aha, so there was an exception being eaten.

Comment: -1 for not showing us the exception.  (And if you don't know how to find the exception you need to learn that right now.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Testing:

```
Integer.parseInt(" 5");  // space before; yields NumberFormatException

Integer.parseInt("5 ");  // space after; yields NumberFormatException
```

Try `trim()` on the `fieldValue` before parsing:

```
out.println("BizInt: "+ Integer.parseInt(fieldValue.trim() )+"\n");
```

Comment: he did say there was no exception, but trimming is a good suggestion all the same.

Comment: Another note to add to the conversation going on in the comments, this answer is probably a better answer than my `replaceAll` comment depending on how the number is being used. This will trim trailing and leading whitespace, so ` 5 ` would be acceptable, but `5 5` would still thrown an exception alerting you to a problem. If you don't care and want to try and parse all the numbers even if a space is in the middle, the `replaceAll` is better.